# Worflow to write results to file in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am running several simulations in Python. Every simulation has the result data: `name, time, cost, error` where name is a string of the actual simulation, time is a int variable, cost is a numpy array or list with different sizes for each simulation and error is a float variable. So far, I always performed just a couple of simulations. I stored the results in separate .txt files. But now I need to run up to 100 simulations and I think this is the perfect time to handle it proper :).

I could store the simulation results e.g. in a dictionary:

```
result = {"SimulationA": {"time": 458,"cost": [12.35, 1.15, 66, 85], "error": 2.45 }"SimulationB":{"time": 512,"cost": [12.35, 66], "error": 12.3 } }
```

If possible, I would like to write everything into an excel or csv document with the structure:

[image]

With an example result:

[image]

What workflow would you recommend (I would prefer something simple, computation time, etc. is not really important)? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can use pandas dataframes https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html to store the info and then just use this function for writing everything into excel https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: I tried this workflow using pandas - exactly what I need. Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the simulations doesn't change, why not just store the information in a numpy array like [[time1, cost1, error1], [time2, cost2, error2],...] and then use numpy to save it as a csv file. Then you just gotta open the file in excel and voila.

Simple code and a picture of the result in excel. You can get as fancy as you want and include headers in the csv file, you can also transpose the data in excel if you prefer the format you showed or swap the 100 and 3 in the random argument. This also might be easiest with lists and then converting the data to a numpy arrays to save it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGbrr.jpg

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(100,3)

np.savetxt('test.csv',data,  delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra commas you have for cost were problematic so I made it into pipes.

```
result = {"SimulationA": {"time": 458,"cost": [12.35, 1.15, 66, 85], "error": 2.45 }, "SimulationB":{"time": 512,"cost": [12.35, 66], "error": 12.3 } }

keys = result.keys()

rows = [
    ',' + ','.join(result.keys()),
    "time," + ','.join([ str(result[x]['time']) for x in keys]),
    "cost," + ','.join([ '|'.join([ str(y) for y in result[x]['cost']]) for x in keys]),
    "error," + ','.join([ str(result[x]['error']) for x in keys])
]

to_write = '\n'.join(rows)

with open('myfile.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(to_write)
```